# API Yandex Map событие при клике на кластер

Tags: javascript, yandex-geocoding-api

Ищу API для

```
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/archive/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/Cluster-docpage/
```

Что конкретно нужно: регулировать зум при открытии кластера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте верхнюю отметку на карте почти не видно, хотелось бы подрегулировать зум так чтобы обе отметки были ближе к центру экрана, при открытии кластера

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

У кластера есть опция zoomMargin https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/archive/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/Clusterer-docpage/#Clusterer__param-options.zoomMargin
Воспользуйтесь ей.